# Скроллинг по якорям при помощи помощи KeyUp и KeyDown

Tags: html, css, html5

Задача проста. Есть одностраничник, в котором нужно сделать скроллинг при нажатии KeyUp и KeyDown (в простонароде "стрелка вверх" и "стрелка вниз")
Буду очень признателен и благодарен.
Пример кода:

HTML

```
<body>
<section id="block1" class="block">
<section id="block2" class="block">
<section id="block3" class="block">
</body
```

CSS

```
#block1 {background: green;}
#block1 {background: yellow;}
#block1 {background: black;}


block {
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

по умолчанию скролинг страницы при нажатии клавиш вверх и вниз происходит,
если Вам нужны якоря то их нужно отрабатывать на определенное действие мышки на странице
например

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Быстрый переход внутри документа</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p><a name="top"></a></p>
  <p>...</p>
  <p><a href="#top">Наверх</a></p>
 </body>
</html>
```

а если нужно управление страницы с помощью клавиатуры то

[Web без мышки](https://habr.com/ru/company/netcracker/blog/273071/)